# Passing messages between 2 parallelly running scripts(python and C++)

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, message-queue, data-synchronization

I currently have 2 scripts running parallelly. The first one(C++) saves data and the second one(python) reads and processes it. Currently I am using a .txt file for this purpose. But that is not very efficient and is hard to synchronize.

I need a way to pass messages between a C++ script and python script synchronously? A Queue kind of structure would be ideal.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need a way to pass messages between a C++ script and python script synchronously? A Queue kind of structure would be ideal.

Comment: Did you search the topic? what is your first solution?

Comment: This is called IPC, which should give you plenty of reading material.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post goes into detail and I think will answer your question

[Share memory between C/C++ and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619531/share-memory-between-c-c-and-python)